# 'tuple' object does not support item assignment & NameError:name

Tags: python

Code

```
import re
letters = ["x","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P"]

def coordSplit(coord):
        splitCoord=[]
        match = re.match(r"([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)", coord, re.I)
        if match:
            splitCoord = match.groups()
        count=0
        for letter in letters:
            if splitCoord[0] == letter:
                print(splitCoord[0])
                splitCoord[1] = str(count) #it can not change this value to a number NameError: name xxx is not defined
            count = count + 1
        return splitCoord

location = "H6"
coordSplit(location)
```

I have been putting this together and i keep getting the error "NameError: name splitCoord is not defined" and "'tuple' object does not support item assignment" can anyone help

Comment: I don't get a NameError. What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
splitCoord = match.groups()
```

Returns a tuple. [As per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups)

Therefore this line:

```
splitCoord[1] = str(count)
```

Will not work as tuples are immutable.

Use:

```
splitCoord = list(match.groups())
```